# Socket connection with Windows.Networking.Sockets and System.Net.Sockets

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, windows-phone-8, client-server

I am trying to create a simple Windows Phone 8.1 (hence Windows.Networking.Sockets) socket client, and Windows 8 server. Unfortunately I am quite new to this task, so I am having problems understanding the obstacles that appear.

I am using [http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this code as a server. However when it comes to the Windows Phone 8.1, it turned out that [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) this tutorial won't work, as there is no way to use the following import:

```
using System.Net.Sockets.
```

Which is the reason why i switched to the following code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150599.aspx (which is btw quite sloppy, and full of errors)

So I embedded the Windows Phone 8.1 part of the code into my application, and it seems to connect correctly to the server, and it even sends data to the server, however the app crashes right after the following statement.

```
"Trying to send data"
```

And the output is exactly like the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured in Project.exe
WinRT information: count
```

Please help me solve the error, as I have vainly spent many hours trying to fix this..

EDIT

Here is the part of code from the mentioned tutorial, that throws the described error

```
// Now try to receive data from server
        try
        {
            OutputView.Text = "";
            StatusText.Text = "Trying to receive data ...";

            DataReader reader = new DataReader(clientSocket.InputStream);
            // Set inputstream options so that we don't have to know the data size
            reader.InputStreamOptions = Partial;
            await reader.LoadAsync(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);  
         }
```

Comment: `count` has nothing to do with sockets.

Comment: @jgauffin cool, that's somewhat helpful. I have pasted the part of code that throws the described error. The whole code is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150599.aspx . Do you see anything that may be causing that message?

Comment: what is the value of count?

Comment: @jgauffin Honestly I have no idea. There is no variable called count. If you however refer to the count property of some object, could you suggest which object has it?

Comment: the stack trace might give a hint

Comment: @jgauffin got it! DataReaderLoadOperation LoadAsync(uint count) !! That is the header for LoadAsync method. So I guess the problem is caused by reader.UnconsumedBufferLength. The value of reader.UnconsumedBufferLength is 0, any sugestions?

Comment: @jgauffin ok once you asked about count, everything started to become clear. I found an alternative way of reading from DataReader, and it seems to work just fine (it doesn't crash the app, however still no message from server, but I will make it work). Thank you for your time. Grab +1
http://bytepacker.blogspot.com/2014/01/windows-store-c-application-reading.html - here is the alternative way